# Weird error testing a reducer (redux toolkit)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redux, jestjs, redux-toolkit

I'm beginner with react and redux and I coded an very simple app to learn it where you can add expenses with a description an amount a date and a note.

I'm testing one of my reducers with jest and I get an error that I cannot understand.
I'm probably missing something but I can't figure out so it would be nice if you could help me out.

So I have one expenseSlice with a reducer action addExpense that prepare the payload just adding an ID and set default values if necessary and add it to the previous state.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { nanoid } from "nanoid"

const expensesDefaultState = []

const expensesSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'expenses',
    initialState: expensesDefaultState,
    reducers: {
        addExpense: {
            reducer: (state, action) => {
                return [
                    ...state,
                    action.payload
                ]
            },
            prepare: (payload) => {
                return {
                    payload: {
                        id: nanoid(),
                        description: payload.description ? payload.description : '',
                        note: payload.note ? payload.note : '',
                        amount: payload.amount ? payload.amount : 0,
                        createdAt: payload.createdAt ? payload.createdAt : 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And in my test file when I test the action the test pass correctly like so :

```
describe('Expenses actions', () => {

    it('should returns an addExpense action object with prepared payload', () => {
        const newExpense = {
            description: 'this is a description',
            amount: 1000,
            createdAt: 0,
            note: 'this is anote'
        }
        expect(addExpense(newExpense)).toEqual({
            type: 'expenses/addExpense',
            payload: {
                id: expect.any(String),
                description: 'this is a description',
                amount: 1000,
                createdAt: 0,
                note: 'this is a note'
            }
        })
    })
```

But when I test the reducer with the same action and expect an id it failed and I get the object without the ID like so :

```
describe('Expense Reducer', () => {

    it('should add an expense', () => {
        const newExpense = {
            description: 'my new expense',
            amount: 1000,
            createdAt: 0,
            note: 'this is a note'
        }
        const state = expenseReducer([], {
            type: 'expenses/addExpense',
            payload: newExpense
        })

        expect(state).toEqual([
            {
                id: expect.any(String),
                description: 'my new expense',
                amount: 1000,
                createdAt: 0,
                note: 'this is a note'
            }
        ])
    })
})
```

And the error :

```
● Expense Reducer › should add an expense

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 1
    + Received  + 0

      Array [
        Object {
          "amount": 1000,
          "createdAt": 0,
          "description": "my new expense",
    -     "id": Any<String>,
          "note": "this is a note",
        },
      ]
```

What I'm missing here or not understanding correctly ?
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you ran the `expensesSlice.reducer` function directly, it's a pure function. So the [prepare callback](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction#using-prepare-callbacks-to-customize-action-contents) will not execute. You can use `store.dispatch(addExpense(newExpense))` to trigger the `prepare` callback and test the changes of the state slice.

`createSlice()` will use `createAction()` to create action creators with or without `prepare` callback and export these action creators as `stateSlice.actions` property. See [v1.7.2/packages/toolkit/src/createSlice.ts#L294](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/v1.7.2/packages/toolkit/src/createSlice.ts#L294)

When the action creators execute like `addExpense(newExpense)`, it will use prepare callback to customize action content(the `id: nanoid()` in your case).

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
import { createSlice, nanoid } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const expensesDefaultState = [];

const expensesSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'expenses',
  initialState: expensesDefaultState,
  reducers: {
    addExpense: {
      reducer: (state, action) => {
        return [...state, action.payload];
      },
      prepare: (payload) => {
        return {
          payload: {
            id: nanoid(),
            description: payload.description ? payload.description : '',
            note: payload.note ? payload.note : '',
            amount: payload.amount ? payload.amount : 0,
            createdAt: payload.createdAt ? payload.createdAt : 0,
          },
        }
      },
    },
  },
});

export const { addExpense } = expensesSlice.actions;
export default expensesSlice.reducer;
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { configureStore, nanoid } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import expenseReducer, { addExpense } from '.';

describe('Expenses actions', () => {
  it('should returns an addExpense action object with prepared payload', () => {
    const newExpense = {
      description: 'this is a description',
      amount: 1000,
      createdAt: 0,
      note: 'this is a note',
    };
    expect(addExpense(newExpense)).toEqual({
      type: 'expenses/addExpense',
      payload: {
        id: expect.any(String),
        description: 'this is a description',
        amount: 1000,
        createdAt: 0,
        note: 'this is a note',
      },
    });
  });

  it('should add an expense', () => {
    const newExpense = {
      id: nanoid(),
      description: 'my new expense',
      amount: 1000,
      createdAt: 0,
      note: 'this is a note',
    };
    const state = expenseReducer([], {
      type: 'expenses/addExpense',
      payload: newExpense,
    });

    expect(state).toEqual([
      {
        id: expect.any(String),
        description: 'my new expense',
        amount: 1000,
        createdAt: 0,
        note: 'this is a note',
      },
    ]);
  });

  it('should add an expense - 2', () => {
    const newExpense = {
      description: 'my new expense',
      amount: 1000,
      createdAt: 0,
      note: 'this is a note',
    };
    const store = configureStore({ reducer: expenseReducer });
    store.dispatch(addExpense(newExpense));
    expect(store.getState()).toEqual([
      {
        id: expect.any(String),
        description: 'my new expense',
        amount: 1000,
        createdAt: 0,
        note: 'this is a note',
      },
    ]);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/72677850/index.test.ts (10.106 s)
  Expenses actions
    ✓ should returns an addExpense action object with prepared payload (2 ms)
    ✓ should add an expense (1 ms)
    ✓ should add an expense - 2 (2 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.577 s, estimated 13 s
```

Comment: Oh thank you ! I got it now!
I wonder if I need to test the dispatch since I know that the prepare function work well with the previous test tho

Comment: In my case changes are not shown in dom