# Testing with store.dispatch(action) doesn't work with redux-toolkit

Tags: unit-testing, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-mock-store

Redux toolkit, redux-mock-store, redux-thunk

I'm struggling to understand the reason why my `store.dispatch(action)` doesn't work whereas `userSlice.reducer` seems to be working in the context of unit testing.

I did read this [Weird error testing a reducer (redux toolkit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72677850/weird-error-testing-a-reducer-redux-toolkit) but it didn't help to resolve the issue.

user.tsx

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { refreshAccessToken } from "../../api/auth";
import { getUserData, patchUserData } from "../../api/user";
import { UserDataResponse } from "../../types/user";
import { RootState } from "../store";
import { logoutUserReducer } from "./auth";
export interface User {
  email?: string;
  name?: string;
  password?: string;
}

export interface InitialStateUser {
  user: User | null;
  userIsLoading: boolean;
  userIsLoaded?: boolean;
}

const initialState: InitialStateUser = {
  user: null,
  userIsLoading: false,
};

export const getUserDataReducer = createAsyncThunk(
  "getUserData",
  async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    // some async code with FETCH API and getUserData()
    }
  }
);

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(getUserDataReducer.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.user = action.payload.user;
        state.userIsLoading = false;
        state.userIsLoaded = true;
      })
      .addCase(getUserDataReducer.pending, (state) => {
        state.userIsLoading = true;
        state.userIsLoaded = false;
      })
      .addCase(getUserDataReducer.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.userIsLoading = false;
        state.userIsLoaded = false;
      })
  },
});

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

user.test.tsx

```
import { AppDispatch, RootState } from "../store";
import configureMockStore, { MockStoreEnhanced } from "redux-mock-store";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { initialIngredientsState } from "./ingredients.test";
import { initialOrderState } from "./order.test";
import userReducer, {
  getUserDataReducer,
  InitialStateUser,
  userSlice,
} from "../slices/user";
import fetchMock from "fetch-mock";
import { BASE_URL } from "../../api";
import { getCookie } from "../../utils/cookieHandler";

const initialUserState: InitialStateUser = {
  user: null,
  userIsLoading: false,
};

const mockStoreInitialState = {
  user: { ...initialUserState }
};

describe("user reducer", () => {
  let store: MockStoreEnhanced<RootState>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore(mockStoreInitialState);
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    fetchMock.restore();
  });
  // WORKS
  it("should getUserData fullfilled", () => {
    const newState = userSlice.reducer(initialUserState, {
      type: "getUserData/fulfilled",
      payload: {
        user: { email: "test@gmail.com", name: "testU2dfd" },
      },
    });

    expect(newState.user).toEqual({
      email: "test@gmail.com",
      name: "testU2dfd",
    });
    expect(newState.userIsLoaded).toBe(true);
  });
  // DOESN't WORK
  it("should getUserData pending", async () => {
    await store.dispatch(getUserDataReducer.pending(""));
    const { userIsLoaded, userIsLoading } = store.getState().user;
    console.log(store.getState());
    expect(userIsLoaded).toBe(false);
    expect(userIsLoading).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

The redux state is simply not updated for the `await store.dispatch(getUserDataReducer.pending(""));`.

```
● user reducer › should getUserData pending

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: false
    Received: undefined
```

Am I missing something here or misunderstood smth?

Comment: When the store is mocked, it only creates and maintains an array of the dispatched actions, it's not actually updating a store object. Opening sentences from the `redux-mock-store` README: "A mock store for testing Redux async action creators and middleware. The mock store will create an array of dispatched actions which serve as an action log for tests."

Answer (score 0):

Ok that looks to be that it's not even intended to update the state according to https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store/issues/71 and from readme https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store

Please note that this library is designed to test the action-related logic, not the reducer-related one